# Node.js - passing object with require

Tags: node.js

I am pretty certain there is a way to pass a variable using require.

So it would look something like this:

```
var model = require('model')(mongoose);
```

With the above line of code, I want to pass my model file my database information (mongoose), so that if I access the same model with a different database, I can pass it different database information.

However, even if the above syntax is correct, I am not sure what my model file itself would have to look like. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
module.exports = function (mongoose) {
  // . . .
  return model;
};
```

Comment: word thx, so I guess I can't assign anything else to module.exports in this case

Comment: You can, functions are objects.
`module.exports.foo = 'bar';` will still work.

Comment: express works that way, it's a function `var app = express();` with methods `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

Answer (score 3):

You can pass moongoose by argument to that file

```
var model = require('model')(mongoose);
```

Your module will look like this, you can make an object in module.exports and can attach multiple properties to that object and in the end return it from the function

```
 module.exports = function (mongoose) {
  model ={};
  model.properties = {};
 model.yourfunction1 = function(){};

  return model;
};
```

> *I guess I can't assign anything else to module.exports in this case?*

Answer to your comment is explained below

Choosing between module.exports and exports depends on you

**For exports**

```
exports.object1 = {};
exports.object2 = {};
```

**For module.exports**

```
module.exports = function(){
myobj={}
myobj.object1 = {};
myobj.object2 = {};
return myobj
}
```

**Now calling it will be different**

**For exports** it will be directly available on file variable

```
var file = require('./file');
console.log(file.object1);
```

**For module.exports** you will execute it like a function by appending function parenthesis so that object can be returned

```
 var file = require('./file')();
console.log(file.myobj.object1);
```